# Overfull hbox with SI package

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have the following code in Latex that is giving me a warning *Overfull \hbox* which I think is caused by my SIunitx package in the table concatenated for *\pm* between two columns. I tried to increase the space of the previous column but I'm still getting the same error. I really appreciate if someone could help me to solve this issue. Thanks!

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption[Statistical analysis of the percentile change of impedance during venous occlusion]{Statistical analysis of the percentile change of impedance during total occlusion. The data represents the median percentile change of impedance per participant, the maximum and minimum value of the occlusion and the difference between these two peak values.}
    \label{tbl:vop delta impedance}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1cm}}
                 S[table-format=1.2]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}
                 S[table-format=1.2]
                 c
                 c
                 c}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Median}}  
        &\textbf{Max} 
        &\textbf{Min}
        &\textbf{Change} \\ 
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{[$\Delta Z \%$]}}
        &\textbf{[$\Delta Z \%$]}
        &\textbf{[$\Delta Z \%$]}
        &\textbf{[$\Delta Z \%$]}\\\midrule
        Participant 1 & -0.26 & 0.09 & -0.20 & -0.47 & 0.26 \\ 
        Participant 2 & -0.58 & 0.21 & -0.03 & -0.69 & 0.66 \\  
        Participant 3 & -0.51 & 0.22 & -0.35 & -1.00 & 0.66 \\  
        Participant 4 & -0.79 & 0.22 & -0.32 & -1.06 & 0.74 \\ 
        Participant 5 & -0.82 & 0.30 & -0.11 & -1.09 & 0.98 \\  
        Participant 6 & -0.33 & 0.09 &  0.03 & -0.41 & 0.43 \\  
        Participant 7 & -0.72 & 0.22 & -0.22 & -0.98 & 0.77 \\  
        Participant 8 & -0.40 & 0.11 & -0.09 & -0.50 & 0.41 \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: If the output looks good to you then you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please always post full minimal examples (such that others can copy and test your code as is, iwthout having to guess parts of your code)

Comment: Also, the first data column contains a minus, so you need to tell it to make space for the minus, so the format for the first S solumn would be `-1.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for column 2 (the first S column) is wrong. The data is similar to `-0.89`, thus you need to make space for a minus, a digit, a decimal marker and two digits. Thus the correct formatting for the first S column is

```
S[table-format=-1.2]
```

as per `siunitx` manual.

Also remember to post full minimal examples instead of sniplets. It makse it a lot easier to help when we do not have to guess your preamble.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for your response. It works like a charm. I spent hours trying to figure out how to solve this. Ok, I'll do a simple example for next time. Thanks again.